# very slow function with two for loops using Arcpy in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, arcpy

I wrote a code which is working perfectly with the small size data, but when I run it over a dataset with 52000 features, it seems to be stuck in the below function:

```
def extract_neighboring_OSM_nodes(ref_nodes,cor_nodes):
    time_start=time.time()
    print "here we start finding neighbors at ", time_start
    for ref_node in ref_nodes:
        buffered_node = ref_node[2].buffer(10)
        for cor_node in cor_nodes:
            if cor_node[2].within(buffered_node):
                ref_node[4].append(cor_node[0])
                cor_node[4].append(ref_node[0])
    #        node[4][:] = [cor_nodes.index(x) for x in cor_nodes if x[2].within(buffered_node)]
    time_end=time.time()
    print "neighbor extraction took ", time_end
    return ref_nodes
```

the ref_node and cor_node are a list of tuples as follows:
[(FID, point, geometry, links, neighbors)]
neighbors is an empty list which is going to be populated in the above function.

As I said the last message printed out is the first print command in this function. it seems that this function is so slow but for 52000 thousand features it should not take 24 hours, should it?
Any Idea where the problem would be or how to make the function faster?

Comment: Think about the number of operations which happen when you have 52000 features.

Comment: I know, but how can I make it faster? it has been running almost over a night :(

Comment: Either change your algorithm to reduce the number of operations, or use a faster language (like C), or both.

Comment: 52000 **features** or **samples**? The `point` has 52000 features?

Comment: @SAM: the points are the features. I need to find the neighbors in 10 meter from the reference point.

Comment: @WeaselFox: I have not used multiprocessing. I dont know how to implement it. could you put it as answer with more explanation please?!

Answer (score 1):

You can try  multiprocessing, here is an example - http://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/using-arcpy-with-multiprocessing-%E2%80%93-part-3/.

Comment: As I understand, for multiprocessing you need to have independent jobs. but here I have a whole dataset whose each node should be check with each node in the other dataset. how can I have independent jobs. except I split my data into several tiles and assign an independent job to each one of them. any other way do you suggest?

Comment: that sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get K Nearest Neighbors of every (or some, it doesn't matter) sample of a dataset or eps neighborhood of samples, there is no need to implement it yourself. There is libraries out there specially for this purpose.

Once they built the data structure (usually some kind of tree) you can query the data for neighborhood of a certain sample. Usually for high dimensional data these data structure are not as good as they are for low dimensions but there is solutions for high dimensional data as well.

One I can recommend here is [KDTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) which has a [Scipy implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

I hope you find it useful as I did.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this library. hopefully my current data structure does not need to be changed. the document says the data needs to be array-like. My structure is a dictionary of tuples. Is that compatible with this class? I am not sure if I can fully understand it.

Comment: [Scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) has some examples about data and how to work with neighborhodd libraries.